# Reading date from Excel using PHP giving one day more

Tags: php, excel, date

I am trying to read dd/mm/yyyy date from Excel. It is behaving very inconsistently. At times it adds one day more to the actual date in the cell and at times give the correct date.

The code:

```
$pdiDate_key = array_search('PDI Date',$excel->sheets[0]['cells'][1]);
```

Comment: Show the relevant parts of the PHP code that you're using.

Comment: Please paste you code here ..

Comment: $pdiDate_key = array_search('PDI Date',$excel->sheets[0]['cells'][1]);

Comment: "I am trying to ready dd/mm/yyyy date from Excel" - Is that value a string you let php "translate" to a unix timestamp? If so, did you take the timezone into account?

Comment: add some code if you want some help

Comment: I read the data as a string and then break the dd, mm and yyyy and then insert into database. But while reading as a string it gives me different date.

Comment: @VolkerK I did not take the timezone into account

Comment: @beta the code is $pdiDate_key = array_search('PDI Date',$excel->sheets[0]['cells'][1]);

Comment: @Ronak: Please use the edit link (located under the tags) to add detail (such as the code you've put in the comments) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code example, I'm going to *guess* that you're using PHP-ExcelReader to retrieve the dates from Excel. If I'm right, then, well, there is a known error in Excel that PHP-ExcelReader doesn't handle. The "bug" report is here:

[SourceForge.net: PHP-ExcelReader: Detail: 2388545 - Wrong Date](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2388545&group_id=99160&atid=623332)

The comments at the bottom of that page include code for a function to fix the error.